# Conflict or some other issue with "usual" ds18b20 vs waterproof version of this sensor

Tags: ds18b20

I have 5 normal ds18b20 sensors and one ds18b20 waterproof sensor and YL-10 adapter (with 4k7 resistor) to connect these sensors to Raspberry Pi.

Problem is, that when I connect my "usual" sensors to adapter - everything works well. I see these sensors in /sys/bus/w1/devices/ and can get sensor data.

But when I add waterproof sensor to 4 usual – everything stops working. I do not see "usual" sensors and see and can only read data from waterproof. If I connect only one waterproof – I can read data from this sensor.

Id of waterproof sensor looks different (28-620191770344) in comparison with "usual" (28-020b92459676)

Could you, please, help me to understand. Is this waterproof sensor corrupted or there is some other problem? How to "debug" this situation? I have long experience in software development, but almost no experience in hardware.

Comment: Add a photo of how your sensors are wired to the Pi.

Comment: I've got another waterproof thermometer and everything works well with it. So I guess it is corrupted sensor. Probably I'll disassemble it and replace the chip later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it was corrupted sensor. I've got new one - and everything works well.